# failure in sqlsrv_query insert into function

Tags: php, sql, database, azure, sqlsrv

I have such a statement to insert data into my azure table:

```
$params = array(1, $blob_name, $owner);
$insert= sqlsrv_query($conn, "INSERT INTO ownership (ID, material_name, owner_name) VALUES (?,?,?)", $params);
```

I really cannot understand, what's the problem, no data is recorded in the table.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You should add `print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);` after query execution  to see what is the error. These two lines seem ok.

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved it. The problem occurs because of I didn't have a clustered index in my table. After creating a clustered index, it works fine.